# How to get formatted text from a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a text editor. Now I am stuck at a point where a user clicks a button and the text is saved to a file (.txt): I am able to get text from the `div`, but not the formatted text (from toolbar of text editor: - bold, italic etc.. via `execommand`)

How to actually do this?

## edit

```
<div id="main">
   <span>Content of #main div goes here</span>
</div>
<a href="#" id="downloadLink">Download the inner html of #main</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
    var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType+';charset=utf-8,'+ encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    link.click(); 
}
var fileName =  'tags.html'; // You can use the .txt extension if you want
$('#downloadLink').click(function(){
    downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'main','text/html');
});
```

Comment: Can you put some of your code here?

Comment: If you are using any wysiwyg editor please read editor documentation

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: no i'm not using any wysiwyg editor , creating my own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that the `.click()` call will fail silently in the browsers I have tried with (Firefox, Chrome), the code *does* send the HTML (not the plain text) to the file.

Here is your code in a more jQuery style, including the change to make the click work:

```js
function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
    var elHtml = $('#' + elId).html();
    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';
    $('<a>').attr('download', filename)
            .attr('href', 'data:' + mimeType+';charset=utf-8,'+ encodeURIComponent(elHtml))
            .get(0)
            .dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"));
}
var fileName =  'tags.html';
$('#downloadLink').click(function(){
    downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'main','text/html');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
   <span>Content of <b>#main</b> <span style="font-family:Courier New">div</span> goes <font color="red">here</font></span>
</div>
<a href="#" id="downloadLink">Download the inner html of #main</a>
```

When opening the download page inside a browser, you'll see the formatting (bold, color, font) is applied correctly.

Comment: well thanks @trincot , the formatting work perfectly with .html , but in .txt format it shows html tag.

Comment: You're welcome! I removed the remark about the .txt file.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to change your 2nd line of javascript to:

```
var elHtml = $("#"+elId).html();
```

So your complete JavaScript will be

```
function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
  var elHtml = $("#"+elId).html();
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';
  link.setAttribute('download', filename);
  link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType+';charset=utf-8,'+ encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
  link.click();
}
var fileName =  'tags.html'; // You can use the .txt extension if you want
$('#downloadLink').click(function(){
  downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'main','text/html');
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Can you explain why the original code would have been wrong? As far as I can tell, they are equivalent.